# Shuffling list of widgets? Tkinter

Tags: python, json, tkinter, widget, shuffle

Finally I have finished this damn thing! Except for one issue.

I have a program quiz program created with tkinter that grabs a dictionary from a list inside a JSON file. Now everything appears to be working fine, except for the shuffling of a list of buttons which remain in the same order (for example, if the answer button is in the far right side of the frame each consecutive questions answer will be in the far right side).

Now each time clickCorrect runs, it runs loadQuestion which configures dictionary values to 4 buttons which then get appended to a list(buttonList). I then shuffle this list and pack the buttons by index (I assume that because they get shuffled each time the program loops each button will be have a different index and so shuffling the order of the buttons) but still the remain in the same order. Is it the packing of the buttons that is causing this? Or is random.shuffle() in the wrong position??

Essentially what I am asking is if packing values(buttons) from a list negating the random.shuffle() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should shuffle the button list just after you've created it (where you have a comment saying `# shuffle button list`). By the way, it would be just as easy to create the list by writing

```
self.buttonList= [self.answerBtn, self.wrong1Btn,
                  self.wrong2Btn, self.wrong3Btn]
```

Comment: Have tried this but buttons still continue on in same order.

Comment: Not on my computer they don't. Successive runs show me 3, 1, 2, 0, then 3, 1, 0, 2, then 2, 3, 0, 1. Which implies the shuffle is working, correct?